# How to avoid the onclick event for children of an div

Tags: jquery

I am moving a DIV once it has been clicked, which works. But the DIV contains form elements and the action also occurs when they are clicked, which I don't want.

I tried adding a function to all children of the DIV, which gets called, but the parent onclick is still being triggered.

```
$("#ControlPanel").click(function() {          
  switch ( $(this).css("top") )
  {
    case "0px":
      $(this).animate({ top: "-100px" });
      break;
    case "-100px":
      $(this).animate({ top: "0px" });
      break;
  }    
});

$("#ControlPanel").children().click(function() { alert(1); return; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

```
 $("#ControlPanel").click(function(event) {   

            if ( event.target == "[object HTMLDivElement]") {

                switch ( $(this).css("top") )
                {
                    case "0px":
                        $(this).animate({ top: "-100px" });
                        break;
                    case "-100px":
                        $(this).animate({ top: "0px" });
                        break;
                }    
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stop the click event propagating up through the DOM which can be achieved using the `stopPropagation()` method. See this jsfiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/5yTnx/

Answer (score 0):

```
.children().click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LbcFj/